# Replacing smiley codes in strings

Tags: java, regex

I am inserting smileys into strings. I have encoded the smileys in a certain format and when before I display the string in a component I need to replace all occurrences of the smiley codes with HTML img tags so they will show up as images. So here is the format of my smileys -

```
&:) ==> smile

&:O ==> shocked

&:( ==> sad

etc...
```

So say I have the following string -

`Did you hear the news &:O. I won a million dollars!! &:)`

I need to find, and then replace all the smiley codes with HTML like

`<img src='file:C:/images/sad.png'/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define this somewhere:

```
static HashMap<String, String> smileys = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

then fill it with the smileys (String) and their html representation:

```
smileys.put("&:)", "<img src='file:C:/images/sad.png'/>");
smileys.put("&:O", "<img src='file:C:/images/sad.png'/>");
smileys.put("&:(", "<img src='file:C:/images/sad.png'/>");
```

replacing smileys is done by replacing every occurrence of a smiley code by its html representation, just loop the hashmap like this:

```
public String replaceSmileys(String text){
    for(Entry<String, String> smiley : smileys.entrySet())
        text = text.replaceAll(smiley.getKey(), smiley.getValue());
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Cheers mate, more elegant than a switch statement or a load of if statements. Think I need double backslashes \\ before the ')' in the smiley codes.

Answer (score 4):

you are best off using `String.replaceAll(String what, String withWhat)` for every type of smiley face you are trying to replace

Comment: Just remember to escape the characters like '(' and ')' with a '\'.

Comment: Short and relevant!  
I just want to note that using this approach, you have to make sure that no smiley starts with the end of another smiley, as this may yield undesirable results when they are parsed.

Comment: @Alex: Ok, im gonna give it a go here

Comment: @neXus: I think you are saying dont have any smiley's ending with &? Which I dont, but good thing to keep in mind though in case I add more down the line.

Comment: @GavinCattell `\\` as escape characters for the parenthesis

Comment: the above was meant to say `\\\`, as in double-backslashes

Comment: Or you could just use the non-regex `replace` method and not worry about all that.

Answer (score 4):

I think you'd be best off using [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) rather than `String.replaceAll` so you don't have to deal with escaping regex patterns... it just does a literal replacement.